# Babelrc file in Docker builds

Tags: docker, webpack, babeljs

I'm running into the errors:

`ERROR in ../~/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js`
`Couldn't find preset "es2015-loose" relative to directory "/app"`

amongst a few other preset not found errors upon building a ReactJS project. It runs on webpackdevserver in dev.

COPY in Docker doesn't copy over dot files by default. Should I be copying .babelrc over to avoid this breaking? How to do this if so. If not, what am I missing/wrong ordering in this build?

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.5

RUN apk update && apk add nodejs

RUN npm i -g webpack \
babel-cli \
node-gyp

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /app/

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

docker-compose

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  webpack:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Docker.doc
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> COPY in Docker doesn't copy over dot files by default.

This is not true. `COPY` in the Dockerfile copies dot files by default. I came across this question as I had faced this issue earlier. For anyone else who may encounter this issue, troubleshoot with the following:

- Check your host/local directory if the dotfiles exists. If you are copying the files over from your OS's GUI, there's a chance that the dotfiles will not be ported over simply because they are hidden.
- Check if you have a `.dockerignore` file that may be ignoring these dotfiles. [More info from .dockerignore docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)